# Can MSBuild in the Microsoft Build Tools 2015 build MS Fakes

Tags: msbuild, microsoft-fakes

Is the MSBuild in the Microsoft Build Tools 2015 capable of building projects that use MS Fakes?

https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=48159

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As far as I know, in order to build projects that uses MS Fakes, you need visual studio enterprise edition ([look at testing tools comparasion](https://www.visualstudio.com/vs/compare/)).

VS 2015 Enterprise is setting up several files into MSBuild tools folder, which includes msbuild targets, and also some *.dll, which contain MSBuild tasks eventually to create fakes binaries.

Summing all up: MSBuild in the Microsoft Build Tools 2015 is capable to build projects that use MS Fakes **if you have VS 2015 Enterprise installed**.